# How to make I18n#t method available in rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, internationalization, rails-i18n

In my test I use `I18n#t` a lot. Is there a way to make this method available without prefixing it with `I18n` (as it is possible in views)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply

```
   include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
```

where appropriate.